# Prove that a matrix is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If A² = I, prove that the matrix A is diagonalizable.

I have computed the eigenvalues to be 1 or -1 but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

I'm thinking along the lines of "since rank(A + I) + rank(A - I) = n, therefore there exists n linearly independent vectors which corresponds to n eigenvectors. Hence, A is diagonalizable". Is that correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

we know that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm 1.$  suppose the dimension of the null space of $A - I$ is $k\ge 1$ and a basis for the null space is $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k\}.$ pick any $y$ not in the null space of $A-I.$ then $Ay - y \ne 0$ and $A(Ay-y) = A^2y-Ay = y-Ay = -1(Ay-y)$  that is $Ay-y$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1.$  therefore the eigenspaces of $A$ span the whole space $R^n$ which implies that $A$ is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $\mu_A$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$. $A$ is diagonalizable iff $$\mu_A(x)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^m (x-x_k),m\leq n$$ with $x_i\neq x_j$ for $i\neq j$ being the eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

You're right the eigenvalues are $\pm1$. Next step is to observe that eigenvectors corresponding to a eigenvector form a linear subspace - therefore you can create a base for these linear subspace. Then you end up with a base $u_j$ and $v_k$ so that $Au_j = u_j$ and $Av_k=-v_k$. Express $A$ in this base.